# NodeJS как искусственно нагрузить процессор | ядро?

Tags: node.js

Изучаю системы мониторинга, для проверки и наглядности хочу создать искусственную нагрузку на NodeJS.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1e3; i++) {
    zlib.gzip(new Buffer(longLongText), (err, data) => {
        console.log(i)
    })
}
```

Данный код загрузил все 4 ядра почти на 100%. Есть ли способ искусственно загрузить процессор на половину +/-? Можно ли контролировать уровень загрузки процессора и время нагрузки?

P.S: NodeJS только осваиваю. Часто встречал советы, что NodeJS процесс работает в один поток. И количество NodeJS процессов советуют запускать равным количеству ядер. Т.е. я думал nodeJS процесс работает на одном ядре, но код выше загрузил мне все 4 ядра. Или это особенность под windiws 10?

В чем смысл запускать по NodeJS процессу на ядро, через pm2 например?

Можно ли на NodeJS загрузить конкретное ядро процессора?